# TinyMCE doesn't allow to put div block into a tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tinymce

Here is the configuration of the plugin.

```
theme: "modern",
    toolbar: "link, image, styleselect, formatselect forecolor backcolor | bold,italic,underline | bullist,numlist,outdent,indent | undo,redo | pastetext,pasteword,selectall | code fullscreen",
    pagebreak_separator: "<p class='page-separator'>&nbsp;</p>",
    plugins: 'link image code fullscreen wordcount textcolor',
    relative_urls: false,
    remove_script_host: false,
    image_caption: true,
    cleanup_on_startup: false,
    trim_span_elements: false,
    verify_html: false,
    cleanup: false,
    convert_urls: false,
    valid_elements: '*[*]',
    valid_children: '*[*]',
    allow_html_in_named_anchor: true,
    allow_unsafe_link_target: true,
    force_br_newlines: false,
    force_p_newlines: false,
    forced_root_block: '',
    document_base_url: (!window.location.origin ? window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host : window.location.origin) + "/"
```

So, what I'm trying to do is to put div block with background image into a tag.
As you can see, I implemented some options to disable validation of source code, but tinymce still editing my code.
Example of what I need:

```html
<a href="http://mosplitka.ru/uploads/Cersaie/cersaie_17.jpg" data-gallery="cersaie">
    <div class="page-gallery-item-bg" style="background-image:url('http://mosplitka.ru/uploads/Cersaie/medium_cersaie_17.jpg'); ">        
    &nbsp;</div>&nbsp;
</a>
```

End what I get after closing Source Code panel:

```html
<div class="page-gallery-item-bg" style="background-image: url('http://mosplitka.ru/uploads/Cersaie/medium_cersaie_17.jpg');">&nbsp;</div>
<a href="http://mosplitka.ru/uploads/Cersaie/cersaie_17.jpg" data-gallery="cersaie">&nbsp; </a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess I found it.
I was sure that parameter valid_children: '*[*]' including all variants of tags, but apparently it's not. So I changed it to valid_children: 'a[div]' and that worked out. Still can't figure out why the first version didn't worked out though. Hope that will help somebody.